# How can an android app track users even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, geolocation, push-notification, google-api, google-places-api

Hi I am very new to android development and so require your help. I am using google places api to get a list of places around a user. Based on this list, I want to send push notifications to users. I have written the code for this function and it is working properly. However, how can I make this function run continuously even when the app is closed ? For example, lets say this function is called collect_send_notification(). I want this particular function to run every 15 minutes in the background even if the user had closed the app. I am sure this is possible but need some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about android [`Services`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AlarmManager to run your code after a certain time. Here is a link to the android reference.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html][1]

and read more about local/global services.